# How to change django version in PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've installed new PyCharm that uses django v1.71(default), but I would like to change it to  v1.68.

How can we achieve this with `PyCharm`?

Comment: You can use `virtualenv`, install Django v1.68 and specify the virtual environment as your Project Interpreter in `PyCharm`; `PyCharm` will use the Django version installed by your virtualenv

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't do that with Pycharm, Pycharm just detects the installed version. You change the version with pip:

```
pip uninstall django # just for explicity
pip install django==1.6.8
```

Make sure you use virtual environments if you run multiple applications on the same machine.

Comment: It's enough to call "pip install django==1.6.8", it detected previous version and uninstalled it automatically. Thx

Comment: you can do it in PyCharm, either by switching virtual environments or installing  appropriate version from `Setttings` > `Project Interpreter`

Comment: This is actually not an answer the question, which asks for the PyCharm interpreter version.

Answer (score 13):

Go to `Settings`->`Project Interpreter`.

Double-click the `Django` package. Activate the check box `Specify version` and select the version you want.

Press the button `Install Package`.

Django will use `pip` in the background to install the package.

Answer (score 3):

In default settings of project.

```
File -> Default Settings -> Default Project -> Project Interpretatoe
```

Comment: like for the straightforward answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Also you can add to your project [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file to make sure whether the current interpreter contains required package, if not - PyCharm ask you to install them.

Answer (score 2):

Go to file>>settings>>Project Interpreter and click the plus sign at the right edge of the popup window and look for django and install it. You need internet access though. It will install the new version.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use virtualenv: create a new virtual environment, install the python you want and keep the path to this version's python.exe file.

Open PyCharm and go to settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can open your project in pycharm and then change your django version by this method:

```
menu->file->setting->project:(your project_name)
```

In package list click on the package you want(here the package we want is Django).

You can delete a package with minus(-) sign and install a package with plus(+) sign...

For example if your previous Django version is 3.0 you can delete it and install even an older version.