# How to install older Django

Tags: django, pycharm

I am using Pycharm and want to install an older version of Django. However, PC only seems to install V2. How can I configure Pycharm to install an older version?

This is about installing an older version, NOT changing a version that has already been installed. I want to configure Pycharm to INSTALL a specific version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change django version in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440489/how-to-change-django-version-in-pycharm)

Comment: Thanks. No, that only tells how to change the version after it is installed. I want to configure PyCharm to install the older version when a project is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for installing through PyCharms UI, you can specify which version of a package you want to install in the package manager. Navigate to

`File -> Settings(or Preferences on MacOs) -> Project: [project name] -> Project interpreter`

and click on the `+` sign under the cog icon. Then search for Django and specify the version you want to install from the drop down menu below the Description field.

However, if you want to install a different version through the terminal, you should write something along the lines of 
`pip install Django==[your_version]`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not looking to change the version, I want to set Pycharm to install an older version, not change a current project to an older version.. Do you know of a way to configure Pycharm to install a different version?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to change the version on **creating a new project** unless you use *your own* interpreter when creating a new project.

So you can first create your virtual environment with the django version you want, and then select that venv when creating a new django project:

```sh
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django==2.1
```

When you want to create a new project, select `Existing Environment` instead of `New environment using...` and use your *custom* venv.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at the moment. The only workaround, as mentioned by Pedram, is to use the existing interpreter with needed version of Django installed.
I filed a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-39298) about that, feel free to vote and leave comments.
You may also find useful the following feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33804